# Excel VBA Application.Activeprinter unable to set

Tags: excel, vba

Getting runtime error when trying to set application.activeprinter
Method 'activeprinter' of object '_application' failed.

MyPrinter value is "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne01:" after using leith ross' function. And in my head it should be correct.
even tried

```
MyPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter
Application.ActivePrinter = MyPrinter
```

But this also gives me te same error.

```
Sub SetDifferentPrinterAsActivePrinter()
    ' The aim for this function is to choose a non-Brady printer and without knowing til correct print port number.
    Dim MyPrinter As String
    
    ' Setting Microsoft Print to PDF as active printer. Everybody has this as a printer, no?
    MyPrinter = FindPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF")
    'MsgBox Application.ActivePrinter
    If MyPrinter = "" Then
        MsgBox "This pc is missing printer: Microsoft Print to PDF. This macro will not work as supposed."
    Else
        'MsgBox "The full name of the printer is " & MyPrinter & "."
        'Setting Microsoft Print to PDF to active printer.
        Application.ActivePrinter = MyPrinter
    End If
End Sub
```

```
'Written: November 28, 2009
'Author:  Leith Ross
'Summary: Finds a printer by name and returns the printer name and port number.

Function FindPrinter(ByVal PrinterName As String) As String

 'This works with Windows 2000 and up
 
  Dim Arr As Variant
  Dim Device As Variant
  Dim Devices As Variant
  Dim Printer As String
  Dim RegObj As Object
  Dim RegValue As String
  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
       
    Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    RegObj.enumvalues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Devices, Arr
    
      For Each Device In Devices
        RegObj.getstringvalue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Device, RegValue
        Printer = Device & " on " & Split(RegValue, ",")(1)
        If InStr(1, Printer, PrinterName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           FindPrinter = Printer
           Exit Function
        End If
      Next
      
End Function
```

Comment: Are you able to manually print on that specific printer? If yes, do such a print and see what "Application.ActivePrinter" returns in Immediate Window after. When you set the active printer, it takes one or two seconds until it is changed. If it does not exist, or it is wrongly installed, it may return such an error, I think.

Comment: Not sure if i'm doing it right... But i dont see anything happen in immediate window when i print. 
And it seems that this code works on other laptops with excel. So i think there is something with my excel or computer. Tried reinstalling microsoft print to pdf as well.
And yes.. manual printing works fine.

Comment: If after printing on that specific printer, `Application.ActivePrinter` does not return anything, then try printing on another printer (a desktop,  network printer) and do the same. Does it return the correct active printer? If yes, it is a matter of printer installation, if not, it should be a problem of Excel...

Comment: It Doesnt change before i reset the watch window. then i can see the latest printer on active printer.

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot get you... So, after manually print something on the problematic printer and **after that** run a simple code line `Debug.print Application.ActivePrinter`, your code does not return anything in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE...). And I suggested to also print on a different (desktop, network) printer and **after printing** run the same code line. Does it return anything in Immediate Window?

Comment: That helped... I now noticed the output is "Microsoft Print to PDF på Ne01:" So it is a localization  issue... Just run a string replace then :D
Thank you for getting me on the right track :)

Comment: Glad I (finally) could help...